# Codeigniter - switch between environments

Tags: php, codeigniter

By default each codeigniter app has defined environment in the ci.php :

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

I need to switch between different countries in my app, and each country has it`s own configuration and database. So I tried to create folder for each country in the 'config' folder and place there all the needed configs. Then I want to select country from a dropdown and switch the environment. Tried like this:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'mexico');
```

but this raises error:

> Message: Constant ENVIRONMENT already defined

How can I do this ?

Comment: post your config.php

Comment: Define the environment in the index.php.

Comment: Its not recommended to change / unset a constant. But here is an answer on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455877/can-you-undefine-or-change-a-constant-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328884/multiple-environments-with-codeigniter

Comment: Don't use environments for localisation.

Answer (score 2):

> **[Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)**: A constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. As the name suggests, that ***value cannot change during the
> execution of the script***

So there is no scope to redefine the value of **ENVIRONMENT** constant as it is already defined. You can use another constant name [except ENVIRONMENT or the other which are already used by codeignitor] or preferable a **variable** to maintain your country related version.

Answer (score 1):

In your **root folder** there is an file call **`index.php`**(image attach below)

[image: 01]

In here if you **define `'development'`**, It will **show your errors** on your Codeigniter framework.

For example if database error occurs it shows this kind of error

[image]

So this you can check whats wrong and all.

> You **can test** it by define to **`testing` or `production`**. So that you will only **get blank page instead of Error Details**.

and i there is **no use of define** a such variable call **`mexico`**

Read This Articles

1. [Handling Multiple Environments](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/environments.html)
2. [What is Development Environment?](http://codeinphp.github.io/post/development-environments-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: Thank you man, the approach was not correct. Figured it out by using $this->load->database() dynamically.

Comment: @stackUnderflow what you need. Can you clear me bit? It will easy to help you out.

Comment: I wanted to switch the country database dynamically. Did it with storing the country in session, checking the country in all controllers constructors and load the proper database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make this in you `index.php`

`switch( $_POST['env']) {
     case 'mexico' : 
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'mexico');
     break;
     //etc ...
}`

Comment: This will determine the config by url. I have only one url with many countries. So when select a country - switch to that country config. Maybe the approach is not correct, maybe I should not do this with environments.

Comment: Well, you can make this solution with `$_POST` variable, but it seems to me this is not a good practice to change environnement constant dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Since ENVIRONMENT is already defined by default in codeigniter, therefore this specific need may achieve through

```
if (!defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'mexico');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ENVIRONMENT is already defined by default in codeigniter, therefore this specific need may achieve through

```
if (!defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'mexico');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> You may pass the selected country id or any short code in URL using get Method and use
>   the below code in your index.php :

Your URL should be like :

**`www.example.com?country=IN` OR**

**www.example.com/controller_name/function_name/IN**

```
if ($_GET['country']=='IN')
   define('ENVIRONMENT', 'india');
elseif ($_GET['country']=='us')
   define('ENVIRONMENT', 'us');
else
   define('ENVIRONMENT', 'uk');
```

Comment: And have a forest of else if else if else if... not a good practice man

Comment: This is exactly what I do in my controller. And error for already defined var occures.